# Why does adding println() at end of printf function not print out the new variable set in Jshell?

Tags: java, jshell

When you don't add println():

```
jshell> System.out.printf("5 * 2 = %d & 8 * 10 = %d", 5*2, 8*10)
5 * 2 = 10 & 8 * 10 = 80$9 ==> java.io.PrintStream@68de145

jshell>
```

when you add println():

```
jshell> System.out.printf("5 * 2 = %d & 8 * 10 = %d", 5*2, 8*10).println()
5 * 2 = 10 & 8 * 10 = 80

jshell>
```

why does println() stop from the new variable set to the print stream being printed out? Shouldn't the variable be printed out in Jshell before the new line from println()? please explain in beginner terms if possible.

Looked on google but found no exact answers.

Comment: `PrintStream printf()` compared to `void println()` - first one returns a `PrintStream`, second does not return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JShell, if an expression results in a value and you do not explicitly assign it to a variable, it will assign the value to a generated variable. You can see this with a simple expression:

```
jshell> 4 + 3
$1 ==> 7
```

The expression `4 + 3` returned a value: `7`. I did not assign it to a variable, so it assigned it to one for me. In this case, it was assigned to the variable `$1`. You can later use this variable (e.g., query it, reassign it, or even drop it).

The same thing is happening in your question with `printf`. It's just a little harder to see because what you printed, and the result of the expression, were printed on the same line. You can separate this out.

This is what you printed:

> ```
> 5 * 2 = 10 & 8 * 10 = 80
> ```

And this is the result of calling `printf`:

> ```
> $9 ==> java.io.PrintStream@68de145
> ```

If you were to add a `%n` (newline) to your `printf` format, you'd see something like:

```
jshell> System.out.printf("5 * 2 = %d & 8 * 10 = %d%n", 5*2, 8*10)
5 * 2 = 10 & 8 * 10 = 80
$2 ==> java.io.PrintStream@887af79
```

So, why do you not see the `$NUMBER ==> value` when you use `println`? Because `println` does not return anything.

- [`PrintStream#printf(String,Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) returns a `PrintStream` object (specifically, it returns the same `PrintStream` object that `printf` was called on). Hence why you can do `printf(...).println()` (i.e., ["method chain"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)) in the first place.
- [`PrintStream#println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) returns `void` (i.e., nothing). There's nothing to (explicitly or implicitly) assign to a variable.

Note that `System.out` is a `PrintStream`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the printf() method serves as a means for formatted printing and is designed to return a reference to the [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class. This PrintStream class includes an array of methods tailored for printing data to the output stream. One of the integral methods within this class is println().
[image]

I guess println() is included as a method in the PrintStream class because it serves as a fundamental and widely used approach to print data with line breaks, thus making it a valuable tool for output operations in Java.